# MongoDB Laravel Connection Issue - ConnectionTimeoutException

Tags: php, laravel, database, mongodb, web

I am facing an issue while attempting to integrate MongoDB and PHP in my project. When I test a regular connection to MongoDB, I don't encounter any problems; however, I wanted to use MongoDB with PHP and Laravel, but I have been unsuccessful in achieving a successful connection.

`The specific error I am encountering is a MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException with the message "No suitable servers found (serverSelectionTryOnce set): [Failed to resolve 'project-cluster.seoukje.mongodb.net']".`

I have ensured that the MongoDB connection URL `(mongodb+srv://id:pass@project-cluster.seoukje.mongodb.net)` is correct. Additionally, I have confirmed that the MongoDB PHP driver is properly installed and configured.

```
I attempted to establish a connection between MongoDB and PHP in my Laravel project. I configured the MongoDB connection URL (mongodb+srv://id:pass@project-cluster.seoukje.mongodb.net) in my Laravel database.php configuration file. I also made sure that the MongoDB PHP driver is installed and enabled in my PHP environment.

Here is my Laravel configuration:

// app.php

'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
        MongoDB\Laravel\MongoDBServiceProvider::class,
]),

// .env

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=project-cluster.seoukje.mongodb.net
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=project-cluster
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=empty

// database.php

 'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'project-cluster'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        ],
```